# Where - to what place - can make sense in this context?

Tags: vocabulary

> "Can we buy all this in London?" Harry wondered aloud. 
>  "If yeh
>   know ***where*** to go," said Hagrid.
>  (Harry Potter and the
>   Sorcerer's Stone)

The two of them already know they are going to London. Then what does ‘where’ mean?

Comment: London's a big place, so you have to know ***where*** in London those things can be bought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What he is saying is: "If you know where to go in London to buy these things." For example, if you want to buy ingredients for a Chinese dish, you would go to Chinatown. If you didn't know where Chinatown was in London, then you would probably not find your ingredients.